# Get image path from SQLITE recycler view Error

Tags: java, android, image, sqlite, android-recyclerview

Can anyone help me to understand my mistake?
What I am trying to achieve is to get the image path from SQLite dB and insert into recycler view. Folder with all images will be in res/drawable.
In adapter class, I have declared `Context and is private global` and in onCreateViewHolder, I added `context = parent.getContext();`
Also in DBModel class, I changed everywhere from bitmap to string and in DB file from blob to TEXT.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DBViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ModelClass objModelClass = objModelClassArrayList.get(position);

    holder.description_sign.setText(objModelClass.getDescription());

    //context = holder.image_sign.getContext();
    //int resAd = getIdentifier(image_path,"drawable",context.getPackageName());
    int i = context.getResources().getIdentifier(objModelClass.getImage(),"drawable",context.getPackageName());
    holder.image_sign.setImageResource(i);



        //holder.image_sign.setImageBitmap(objModelClass.getImage());  <- It works but i don't want that.
    }


>  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>             Process: com.example.dissertation, PID: 5449
>             java.lang.NullPointerException: name is null
>                 at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getIdentifier(ResourcesImpl.java:240)
>                 at android.content.res.Resources.getIdentifier(Resources.java:1927)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this code block?

```
String uri = "@drawable/" + objModelClass.getImage();  

int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());

Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
holder.image_sign.setImageDrawable(res);
```

Comment: I have tried but i am facing a problem with getResources(line 2) is not found.

Comment: thx for your help i found the solution. I have used your technique with small changes

Answer (score 0):

```
    ModelClass objModelClass = objModelClassArrayList.get(position);

    holder.description_sign.setText(objModelClass.getDescription())
    String uri = "@drawable/" + objModelClass.getImage();
    int imageResource = holder.itemView.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, holder.itemView.getContext().getPackageName());
    holder.image_sign.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

It should also be declared Context as global and in onCreateViewHolder to refer to it context = parent.getContext();